# Simple 'or' isn't working as expected

Tags: ruby, rubygame

I'm running into an interesting issue with the relatively simple assignment below. Each of the parenthesized chunks in the beginning evaluate to *nil*, leaving `Rubygame::Surface.new` as the value that `@image` ought to be assigned to. Unfortunately on the next line where I set `@rect`, it throws a *NoMethodError* because `@image` is *nil*.

```
@image = (image unless image.nil?) or 
         (Rubygame::Surface.autoload(image_file) unless image_file.nil?) or 
         (Rubygame::Surface.autoload("#{@name}.png") unless @name.nil?) or 
         Rubygame::Surface.new([16, 16])
@rect = Rubygame::Rect.new [0, 0], [@image.width, @image.height]
```

Similar tests run through IRB work as expected, so I'm pretty sure the 'or' statement is well-formed, but I can't figure out why it isn't returning the new Surface when everything else is *nil*.

Comment: Only one first line is already blowing my head...

Comment: `image unless image.nil?` -> `image if image` -> `image`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `or` and `and` keywords in Ruby have **very, very low precedence**. Even lower than the assignment operator `=`. So simply replace them with `||` and `&&` respectively (both binding tighter than `=`), and it should work as you expect. Ruby's [operator precedence is listed here](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4).

In addition to that, I would say your code is very dense. Consider refactoring it to something like the following, which I think conveys the intent of your code much better.

```
@image = case
  when image then image
  when image_file then Rubygame::Surface.autoload(image_file)
  when @name then Rubygame::Surface.autoload("#{@name}.png")
  else Rubygame::Surface.new([16, 16])
end

@rect = Rubygame::Rect.new [0, 0], [@image.width, @image.height]
```

Comment: Operator precedence was the issue in my version, but I attempted to use your case version and I'm still getting _nil_ returned. The method arguments satisfy the first when-condition (`image = Rubygame::Surface.new([640, 480])`), but if you omit the argument to a case statement, what is it comparing against?

Comment: The way `case` is used here, without argument, simply tests each expression after `when` for truthiness. It stops when it finds the first truthy value. In the example I gave, the only way to get `nil` assigned to `@image`, is if `Rubygame::Surface.autoload` or `Rubygame::Surface.new` return `nil` in a particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried further levels of parentheses?

```
@image = ((image unless image.nil?) or 
         (Rubygame::Surface.autoload(image_file) unless image_file.nil?) or 
         (Rubygame::Surface.autoload("#{@name}.png") unless @name.nil?) or 
         Rubygame::Surface.new([16, 16]))
```

Comment: A good general thing to try in any Ruby situation with those and/ors.  This has been the solution to 90% of my conditional problems.

Comment: I just remember from Perl that `or` has a lower precedence than `||` and `=`. Wrote code flooded with parentheses until I figured that out.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using RubyGame? The [Gosu](http://www.libgosu.org) game development framework for Ruby is faster and more popular.