# Ruby beginner -- which of these conditional statements is best?

Tags: ruby

```
if !store.url.nil? and store.url != store.new_data.url
```

OR

```
if ! store.url.nil? && store.url != store.new_data.url
```

OR

```
if (!store.url.nil? && store.url != store.new_data.url)
```

Main items I'd like to get advice on:

1. Is it better to put a space after the bang?
2. **&&**  -or-  **and**
3. *||*  -or-  **or**

Comment: @Close voter: `&&` is not synonymous with `and`, nor `||` synonymous with `or`, so this is not a "not constructive" question.

Comment: @Andrew. I beg to differ. They may not be synonymous but still I think it's a valid doubt. It looks more like a partly duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/ruby-difference-between-and-or

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must always use "&&" or "||" in an boolean statement.

"and" and "or" should be used for control flow like if or unless.

If you're working in Rails, you can also do

```
if store.url.present? && store.new_data.url != store.url
```

Do not put spaces after the negation exclamation. Using brackets willy nilly is frowned upon in the general ruby coding conventions, so avoid if you can.

Comment: That's not true at all. `and` is usually better than `&&`, because it's lower precedence.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write:

```
if store.url && store.url != store.new_data.url
```

(Write `store.url.present?` if a blank URL string is to be considered a "nil" value)

Notes:

- Don't use `nil?` unless you explicitly want to distinguish between `nil` and `false` (which are the only false values in Ruby). These cases are rare.
- No spaces after the bang.
- Use the more idiomatic `&&`/`||` over `and`/`or`.
- Don't write parentheses covering a complete if/unless expression, they are unnecessary (and not idiomatic) in Ruby.

Comment: No, no, no. The higher precedence of `&&` will usually necessitate *more* parentheses in statements like this. `and` is the correct choice here.

Comment: @Marnen: you're right, a higher precedence will require more parentheses in some situations, answer edited. However, the idiomatic usage is overwhelming, people uses &&, ||. It's my understanding  that core Ruby core devs even reject patches containing and/or for this usage.

Comment: No. It's more idiomatic to use `and` in almost all cases (it's more English-like and therefore more readable). I believe Matz himself has suggested that, though I could be wrong. This is the first I've ever heard of the core team rejecting `and`. Your source?

Comment: I had to search because I didn't remember where I had read it, it was a statement by @Jörg W Mittag here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/ruby-difference-between-and-or. BTW, you say that "and" is more idiomatic because is more English-like, but "idiomatic" is what the community uses more. For the code I've read, programmers overwhelmingly prefer &&/|| over and/or.

Comment: This programmer does not. `&&` should be used for complex Boolean math, not simple conditionals. And the Rails core team does lots of things that I'd consider poor practice. Jörg is just wrong, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:
`if store.url and store.url != store.new_data.url`
or (if you're using Rails or Ruby 1.9)
`if store.try(:url) != store.new_data.url`

Remember, `nil` is falsy in Ruby.