# Checking if variable is nil or empty in a single line using or operator

Tags: ruby

I have absolutely no experience in Ruby, but am trying to debug an issue in [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm). Sometimes, when running FPM, I get the following stack trace:

```
output': undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I traced this error back to this line ([rpm.rb, line 419](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/blob/master/lib/fpm/package/rpm.rb#L419)):

```
if @epoch.nil? or @epoch.empty?
   @logger.warn("no value for epoch is set, defaulting to nil")
   return nil
end
```

[This blog post](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) says the following about the `or` operator:

> The best way to think about the chains constructed with or is as
>   series of fallbacks: try this, if that fails try this, and so on

This leads me to believe that in the above code fragment, if `epoch.nil?` evaluates to true, it will not attempt to check `epoch.empty?`, but a simple codepad shows that to be wrong (http://codepad.org/qI7rLvBX)

```
str = nil
puts str.nil? or str.empty?

Output:
Line 2: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
true
```

if I change it the operator to `||`, then the short-circuiting works correctly - if `epoch.nil?` evaluates to true, it does not attempt to evaluate `epoch.empty?`.

Am I misunderstanding something about the `or` operator? And is the way FPM is checking for nil or empty incorrect?

Comment: what ruby version are you using?

Comment: Also tried for 1.8.7. Didn't get error for `if @epoch.nil? or @epoch.empty?`. And logically, this line should not raise error, as `if` has lower precedence than `or`. See http://codepad.org/JTacEmoj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of operator precedence. `||` has a higher precedence than `or`.
You should write it like:

```
str = nil
puts (str.nil? or str.empty?)
puts str.nil? || str.empty?
```

See more in [Difference between "or" and || in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby)

For the issue of FPM, I have tried under Ruby 1.8.6, 1.9.3, 2.0.0, and did not get error with `or` expression.

Comment: Adding the parenthesis fixes the issue - so then, as you said, the issue is only in my codepad because `puts` has a higher precedence than `or`, but not in FPM since `if` has a lower precedence than `or`. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 3):

You could skip the whole problem by noting that [`nil.to_s` is an empty string](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s):

> **NilClass#to_s → ""**
>
> Always returns the empty string.

Given that, you could say:

```
if @epoch.to_s.empty?
```

This is a useful trick for avoiding a bunch of noisy `nil?` tests when dealing with strings.