# Ruby logical operator

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

I don't know what makes a difference here.

```
a = 24
b = 60
comp1 = a > 42 or b == 60
comp1 # => false
comp2 = (a > 42 or b == 60)
comp2 # => true
```

Could someone explain what's going on and why the return values are different?

Comment: You may be [confusing `or` with `||` here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby)

Comment: `or` and `and` are meant to be used as control flow operators. Whereas `||` and `&&` are meant to be logical operators.

Comment: @engineersmnky Given that every expression in Ruby has an evaluated value, that does not make any difference.

Comment: @sawa: semantics, man. Conveying message and all that. Then again, lowered precedence helps with using for control flow.

Comment: Helps to remember that `and, or` are sometimes referred to as logical _composition_ operators.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Control flow operators do mean something (and more than semantically) even if @sawa doesn't think so. Take this for example `a = 12 and a += 1 #=> 13` vs `b =12 && b += 1 #=> NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass` this is because the first version says assign `a` and if `a` is not falsey then evaluate `a += 1` the second version the assingment will occur after the logical expression is evaluated and since `12` is truthy it then moves on to `b += 1` but `b`  is still `nil` so it raises an error.

Comment: @engineersmnky: yeah, I know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the strength of the operator binding, as operators are applied in [a very particular order](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html#top).

`or` is very loose, it has the lowest priority. The `||` operator is very strong, the opposite of that. Note how in that table `||` comes before `=`, but `or` comes after? That has implications.

From your example:

```
comp1 = a > 42 or b == 60
```

This is how Ruby interprets this:

```
(comp1 = (a > 42)) or (b == 60)
```

As such, the entire statement returns `true` but `comp1` is assigned `false` because it doesn't capture the whole thing.

So to fix that, just use the strong binding version:

```
comp1 = a > 42 || b == 60
# => true
```

Answer (score 3):

It has all to do with operator precedence. `or` has lower priority than `=`, so

```
comp1 = a > 42 or b == 60
```

is executed as

```
(comp1 = a > 42) or (b == 60)
```

You need to enforce precedence by parentheses. Or be a good ruby coder and never* use `and/or` (use `&&`/`||` instead)

<sub>* never, unless you know what you're doing. A rule of thumb is: &&/|| for logical operations, and/or - for control flow.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for adding the `*` to *never* and for explaining that `and` and `or` are for control flow not logical operations.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, assignment (`=`), has higher precedence than the written `or` operator, so the first line is interpreted as this:

```
(comp1 = a > 42) or (b == 60)
```

That means that `comp1` is being assigned the value of `a > 42`, which is obviously false. The parenthesis in the second expression resolve the issue.

In general, in Ruby, you use `||` instead of `or`, and likewise, `&&` in place of `and`.