# Ruby syntax "OR" operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

I have a Rails project and one of my classes has:

```
def include_stuff?(str)
  str.include? '.' || str.include? '-'
end
```

Which just give me:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
cpf.include? '.' || cpf.include? '-'
                                  ^
```

I changed the code to:

```
def include_stuff?(str)
  str.include? '.' or str.include? '-'
end
```

And no error was thrown.

I tried this too, with success:

```
def include_stuff?(str)
  str.include?('.') || str.include?('-')
end
```

Why can't Ruby understand the statement with double pipe, but can understand the statement with the `or` operator.

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2

Comment: Precedence rules, friend. Precedence rules.

Answer (score 3):

`||` and `or` are not the same in Ruby (see [Difference between "or" and || in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby)) because of precedence.

So your statement:

```
str.include? '.' or str.include? '-'
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
str.include?('.' || str.include?('-'))
```

Comment: Just continuing the logic. The last statement will become ' str.include?('.') ' right?

And thanks for the fast answer, as a newbie in SO, the velocity here are awesome.

Comment: @VictorSilvadosSantos Yes, that's correct. As in most languages, if the first argument of a logical disjunction (whether `||` or `or`) is truthy, the second argument isn't even evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with operator precedence. `or` is much lower than `||`.

It's trying to parse `cpf.include? '.' || cpf.include? '-'` as `cpf.include?('.' || cpf.include? '-' )` and gets confused as the second `include?` doesn't have brackets.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence

Note `or` and `||` are not the same thing.

see http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/

> Conclusion
>
> `and` and `or`, despite an apparent similarity to `&&` and `||`, have very different roles. and and or are control-flow modifiers like `if` and `unless`. When used in this capacity their low precedence is a virtue rather than an annoyance.

Comment: As (the invalid) `cpf.include?(('.' || cpf.include?) '-')` then?