# Replacing all vowels in a string

Tags: ruby, string

I got an exercise to replace any vowel from a string with an `X`. The following returns an error. I am not sure why. I don't want to use `String#replace`.

```
def disemvowel (string)
  vowels_caps = [A, E, I, O, U]
  vowels_notcaps = [a, e, i, o, u]

  stringarray = string.split("")

  stringarray.each do |letter|
    if vowels_caps.include? letter or vowels_notcaps.include? letter
        letter = "X" 
    end
  end

  string = stringarray.join("")

  string
end

disemvowel(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
```

Comment: When saying something produces an error it's a good idea to say what the error is.

Comment: ...including the line on which it occurred.

Answer (score 8):

Excellent choice of method name.

You have a few problems; let's take them one at a time. First:

```
undefined local variable or method `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

When you write strings, you need to wrap them in `''` or `""`. Ruby is trying to interpret `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` as a variable like `letter` or `stringarray`. So that should look like:

```
disemvowel('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Next, `uninitialized constant A`. This is the same problem, happening when Ruby tries to evaluate `vowel_caps` and `vowel_notcaps`:

```
vowels_caps = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
```

Creating arrays of strings is common, so there's a shorthand using `%w` that easily creates an array of words, separated by whitespace:

```
vowels_caps = %w[A E I O U]
vowels_notcaps = %w[a e i o u]
```

Now you run the script, but seemingly nothing happens. Make sure you print your output:

```
puts disemvowel('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Great, so there's some output, but it's just the alphabet again. The failure here is that you expect `letter = "X"` to replace the letter inside `stringarray`, but it does not. `letter` is its own variable, independent of `stringarray` - it's not a pointer into the array itself. There are a few ways to fix this, but I think the clearest might be to switch from `each` to `map`, since you're already trying to `join` the result afterward. Where `each` returns the original array, `map` returns an array containing the result of each iteration.

```
resultarray = stringarray.map do |letter|
  if vowels_caps.include? letter or vowels_notcaps.include? letter
    "X"
  else
    letter
  end
end
puts resultarray.inspect
```

I've just put that print there temporarily to verify that indeed the `X` is subbed in for each vowel:

```
["X", "b", "c", "d", "X", "f", "g", "h", "X", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "X", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "X", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

As a side note—and this can start something of a war occasionally—you should prefer `||` over `or` in boolean logic. The operators [have different precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby) and using `or` this way [can surprise you](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

```
if vowels_caps.include?(letter) || vowels_notcaps.include?(letter)
```

Now just `join` it back up like you have been, and there's actually no need to reassign it to `string`. Ruby returns the value of the last expression in the function, which can just be:

```
resultarray.join("")
```

And voila!

```
$ ruby disemvowel.rb
XbcdXfghXjklmnXpqrstXvwxyz
```

Comment: Great answer. In your opinion is it a bad idea to use the `!` operator on map in this case?

Comment: Not at all, just depends what you want. I err towards non-destructive operators, but if the string/array were significantly long, using `map!` to avoid building a second array would be beneficial.

Comment: You are an amazing hero! Thanks so much for you detailed response. I learned a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as this. Use the [`String#tr`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr)

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.tr('aeiouAEIOU', 'X')
#=> "XbcdXfghXjklmnXpqrstXvwxyz"

'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.tr('aeiouAEIOU', 'X')
#=> "XBCDXFGHXJKLMNXPQRSTXVWXYZXbcdXfghXjklmnXpqrstXvwxyz"
```

Comment: While this is a proper solution to the exercise, it doesn't answer the question why the code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
str.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, 'x')
# => "xbcdxfghxjklmnxpqrstxvwxyz"
```

Comment: While this is a working solution to the exercise, it doesn't answer the question why the code above doesn't work. You can skip the `downcase` by making your regexp case-insensitive (`/[aeiou]/i`).