# ruby more than 2 alternative in or-operator

Tags: ruby

I have this line of code:

```
if self.include?("van " || "de " || "von ")
```

why doesn't the block included after this line execute when the third alternative of the or-operator is true?

When my string is `"von wartburg"` the block doesn't execute, but when my string contains `"van"` or `"de"` then it does.

Comment: "or 'de' then it does" - nope. it works only for "van"

Comment: thanks for the English language corrections ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.include?("van " || "de " || "von ")
```

Will ***ALWAYS*** evaluate to

```
self.include?("van ")
```

Why? Because of how `||` works.

```
"van " || "de " || "von "
# ↑↑↑↑↑↑ evaluates to "van " and does not give a slightest shoe about the rest
```

See [String#`include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) - it accepts a substring and offset as arguments.

What you need is the following:

```
["van ", "de ", "von "].any? { |substring| self.include?(substring) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'or' will always evaluate "van " [because of how || works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby).

Try using a regular expression like:

```
self =~ /^(van\ |de\ |von\ )/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
if self.include?("van ") || self.include?("de ") || self.include?("von ")
```

Having the `||` inside the call to `include?` makes it only evaluate the first string. You want to test `include?` for each case.

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't work for "de " either

```
2.3.0 :004 > "van test".include?("van " || "de " || "von ")
 => true
2.3.0 :005 > "de test".include?("van " || "de " || "von ")
 => false
2.3.0 :006 > "von test".include?("van " || "de " || "von ")
 => false
```

When you run `String#include?("van " || "de " || "von ")`
you pass only one argument to the function: `"van " || "de " || "von "`.

Boolean OR (`||`) will return the first element of the list that evaluates to true. So this is strictly identical to `String#include?("van ")`.

I know only two ways to do what you were trying to do in just one line :

- You can make a table of substrings to test and use `any?` over it

  `["van ", "de ", "von "].any? { |s| string.include?(s) }`
- Or you can use a regex (in which the or operator (`|`) does exactly what you want)

  `/van |de |von / =~ string`