# I'm not sure why this simple code does not work

Tags: ruby

I want someone to enter number `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"3"`, and if the number is correct, want to say `"ok"`. If not, I want to say `"enter 1 or 2 or 3"`.

This is my code:

```
puts "enter 1 or 2 or 3"
num = gets.to_i

if num == 1 or 2 or 3
  puts "ok"
else
  puts "enter 1 or 2 or 3"
end
```

When I enter an incorrect answer such as `"e"` or `"p"`, it still says "ok".

Why is it the case?

Comment: Do you want the program to keep prompting the user until they correctly choose `1`, `2` or `3`?

Answer (score 5):

Let's first examine why you are obtaining incorrect results.

If `a` equals `false` or `nil` (is *falsy*, meaning logically `false`), `a or b` returns the value of `b`. If `a` equals any other value (is *truthy*, meaning logically `true`), `a or b` returns `a`.

Suppose we have an expression `a op1 b op2 c`, where `op1` and `op2` are operators (e.g., `a == b or c`). This could be evaluated `(a op1 b) op2 c` or `a op1 (b op2 c)`, where parentheses have the highest precedence.

The precedence of Ruby's operators (most implemented as methods) is given [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html). Note that `==` has higher precedence than `or`. Moreover, for any given operator `op`, `a op b op c` is evaluated `(a op b) op c`.

The expression `num == 1 or 2 or 3` is therefore evaluated

```
((num == 1) or 2) or 3
```

Now consider the value of this expression, depending on the value of `num`.

```
num = 1
((num == 1) or 2) or 3 => (true or 2) or 3 => true or 3 => true

num != 1
((num == 1) or 2) or 3 => (false or 2) or 3 => 2 or 3 => 2
```

Here are some ways to obtain your desired result.

```
(num == 1) or (num == 2) or (num == 3)
(num == 1) || (num == 2) || (num == 3)
[1, 2, 3].include?(num)
[1, 2, 3] & [num] == [num]
([num] - [1, 2, 3]).empty?
```

Because of the precedence rules for operators, the parentheses are not needed in the first two expressions, but it can be argued they clarify the code, at least for some readers. (I would include them.)

Regarding the choice between using `or` or `||`, see [this SO queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby), particularly the second answer. In practice, `or` is rarely used.

See [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F), [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-26) and [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-2D).

To round out the possibilities, one could conceivably use a case statement.

```
case num
when 1, 2, 3 then true
else false
end
```

If, as here, the acceptable values of `num` form a range, one could write either of the following.

```
num.between?(1, 3)
(1..3).cover?(num)
(num >= 1) && (num <= 3)
```

See [Comparable#between](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) and [Range#cover?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html). Again, the parentheses in the latter are optional.

Comment: Unlike every other example in this well-written answer, `Range#cover` is different in that it will return `true` for non-integers. For example, `(1..3).cover?(2.5)` returns `true`. You could also use `num.between?(1, 3)` to achieve the same result.

Comment: @moveson, good points, but of course `num = gets.to_i` will be an integer  (even `'cat\n'.to_i #=> 0`). Some data checks may be needed for `str = gets` prior to the conversion of `str` to an integer. I added `num.between?` to my answer. All three range-related expressions return `true` when `num = 2.5`.

Comment: You are correct as usual, sir! I just wanted to point it out in the event this answer is reviewed by someone looking at different ways to solve the problem of multiple equality comparisons, when the inputs may not be so clearly defined. With three or more elements, it feels to me like `[elements].include?(input)` has the edge from a usability and readability perspective.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `num == 1 or 2 or 3` evaluates to `true` always, as `2` is considered logically true, and using an ``` or`` operator with logically true value returns a ```true` result always.

The correct way to compare is like this

```
puts "enter 1 or 2 or 3"
num = gets.to_i

if num == 1 or num == 2 or num == 3
    puts "ok"
else
    puts "enter 1 or 2 or 3"
end
```

Here, you are comparing the value of variable with right literal.

Comment: Another option for the `if` statement would be, `if [1, 2, 3].include?(num)`