# Ruby Double Pipes Assignment

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

Just tripped over an instruction that is unclear:

```
a = 5 || 3                       # ==> 5
verdict = true || false          # ==> true
```

Since `||` is the same as `or`, how and/or why would this statement be used?  It doesn't really demonstrate any decision making other than choosing the first option always.

I know the `||=` assignment, but this is different.  Looking for clarification on the usage above of `||` alone.

Comment: `number = options[:number] || 42`

Comment: Where did you stumble on this example? Used like this it does not make any sense.

Comment: @DennyMueller If you are asking me (not clear), I saw it in a video yesterday, don't have url.  It doesn't make sense, but it takes on meaning if it becomes boolean.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin That hasn't explained anything, just repeated the question in another example.

Comment: @Rich_F the example of @AlekseiMatiushkin actually makes more sense since `options[:number]` could be `nil` and with `number = options[:number] || 42` you make sure either the number in the `options` hash is assigned or `42` . 
`nil || 42 #=> 42`.

Comment: @DennyMueller OK, that's a `conditional` then.  That comes back to the `boolean` sense in that if the first value defaults, then second value becomes the value.  Can I assume first value takes preference?

Comment: yes that's correct its more like a `if true; else; `

Comment: @DennyMueller Good to know.  Learned something.

Comment: @Rich_F [Difference between `or` and `||`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = b || c
```

What this statement does is, it tells Ruby to 'assign the value of `b` to `a`, unless `b` is falsy, if `b` is falsy, assign the value of `c` to `a`. In case `b` isn't falsy, the `c` statement won't get executed.

A good example where you could use this is if you're getting a variable from somewhere and you're not sure if it's going to be nil or not, so you create a variable like `c` as a second option.

If you have a method that takes in a hash as a parameter for example, and you want to return the value of the element from the hash that has the key `'b'` for example, but the hash parameter won't always have a `'b'` key, so you write something like this

```
def value_of_b(hash)
  b_val = hash['b'] || 'unknown'
  puts "The value of b is :#{b_val}"
end

h = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}

value_of_b(h)
#=>The value of b is :2

m = {'a' => 1}

value_of_b(m)
#=>The value of b is :unknown
```

Another example that comes to my mind is accessing an array element that doesn't exist

```
[1,2,3][3] || "default"
#=> "default"
```

Or having a default value for Rails params hash:

```
@name = params[:name] || "no name provided"
```

Comment: OK, so precedence.  I've not tripped over that term **falsey**.  For something like this I usually turn to a `ternary`.  Your `array` example probably shows it best.  It has a built-in conditional.

Comment: Sorry, it's falsy. It was a typo. [Falsy](https://riptutorial.com/ruby/example/2092/truthy-and-falsy-values) is usually the term used to describe a variable that is either `nil` or `false`

Comment: @Viktor _falsey_ (or _falsy_) is used to describe a variable that is treated as `false` in boolean expressions. In different languages it might include more (like `0` or `""` in [tag:php].)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Ya that's what Viktor was indicating.  So the conditional is on the first value, second value being the default.  I've not run across this.

Comment: Not necessarily. If one has `local_defaults` and `global_defaults`, and `args` passed from the outside, it might take a form `args[:param] || local_defaults[:param] || global_defaults[:param]`. Ot, think about blog entry in the database `post[:title] || post[:excerpt] || post[:body][0..63]`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `||` is a _short-circuit operator_, i.e. the right-hand side is evaluated only if the left-hand side is falsey.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're right, it doesn't add any value to the answer. Thank you

Comment: You can also do cool stuff like foo = condition && value_if_condition_true || value_if_condition_false