# Rails instance variable not assigned within 'or' in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 5.2 project; In a controller I have:

```
  def show
    binding.pry
    @correct_user = false
    some_method or (@correct_user=correct_user) or return
    # -> here the value of @correct_user is false
    # some other code here
  end
```

`some_method` evaluates to false; `correct_user` method evaluates to true here; `return` is not reached
but right after that `@correct_user` var value is `false` why is this;

I made another test in 'rails console':

```
irb(main):001:0> def f
irb(main):002:1>   return false
irb(main):003:1> end
=> :f
irb(main):004:0> def a
irb(main):005:1>   return true
irb(main):006:1> end
=> :a
irb(main):007:0> @t=false
=> false
irb(main):008:0> f or (@t=a) or return
=> true
irb(main):009:0> @t
=> true
```

So this works as would expect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "or" and || in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby)

Comment: It does not. I am aware of the difference of these two, and I am using `or` for flow control here, so there's another problem. Thank for the suggestion, though.