# Ruby on Rails incorrectly evaluates logical 'OR' operator

Tags: ruby

I have a simple bit of code running inside a rails model.

```
num = 3
result = num == 0 or num == 2 or num == 3
```

The ***result*** in the above statement should be evaluated to **true**. But for some reason rails evaluate this to be **false** when the method is called from the a rails view.

Just to confirm that it is an issue with rails when used with a view, I used the rails console to evaluate the exact same code. the rails console correctly evaluated that statement to **true**.

```
Rails Version: 5.1.7
Ruby Version: 2.6.5-p114
```

Thanks

Comment: The `or` operator has a lower precedence - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby

Comment: It is generally a good idea to pretend that Ruby doesn't have `and`, `or`, and `not` operators, their precedence tends to cause a lot of confusion and problems. Use `&&`, `||`, and `!` instead and there will be less confusion.