# nil || false and false || nil in ruby

Tags: ruby, null

`nil || false` returns `false` and `false || nil` returns `nil`. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: For bonus points explain why `nil || false and false || nil` evaluates to false

Comment: @pguardiario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840488/operator-precedence-for-and-in-ruby

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Ruby, everything is an expression, and an expression will return the last value evaluated within it.

For both of your examples, the left side of the `||` expression evaluates to a falsy value, so Ruby then evaluates the right side, and returns it.

Answer (score 4):

As the others pointed out, `||` first evaluates the expression on the left. If it is "true" (anything except `false` or `nil`), it returns that. Otherwise, it evaluates the expression on the right, and returns it (no matter what it is).

This makes `||` useful for a lot more than just boolean tests. For example, I just used it the other day when writing some code for the `chronic` gem:

```
@now = options[:now] || Chronic.time_class.now
```

That means: "if the `options` hash includes  a `:now` value, store that in `@now`. Otherwise, fall back on `Chronic.time_class.now` as a default". I'm sure you can think of lots of possible applications in your own programs.

`&&` is analogous: it first evaluates the expression on the left, and if it evaluates to `false` or `nil`, it returns that. Otherwise, it evaluates the expression on the right, and returns it (no matter what it is).

This means `&&` is *also* useful for a lot more than just boolean tests. You can use it to squeeze two lines of code into one. For example:

```
do_something && do_something_else
```

(That only works if you know that the return value of `do_something` will never be `false` or `nil`!)

You can also use `&&` to squeeze a "guard" expression on the same line as what it is "guarding":

```
message && send_message(message)
```

Which could replace:

```
unless message.nil?
  send_message(message)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`||` returns the result of the last expression evaluated. If it evaluates the LHS and finds a `true` value, you get the LHS; otherwise, you get the RHS (no matter what that RHS might be).